# Application of higher-dimensional knot theory

Tags: geometric-topology, knot-theory, knot-invariants

There are quite a few applications to classical (1-dimensional) knot theory, such as knotted proteins, DNA,... Are there any potential applications of 2-dimensional knot theory? E.g. knotted surfaces in 4-dimensional manifolds?

Comment: One can realize every smooth closed oriented 4-manifold as a branched covering over $S^4$ with branch-locus a surface in $S^4$, so studying surface knots is useful if you care about 4D topology. But, afaik, there are no applications in the sense of applied math.